# SSRS Export to Excel print format not default to 11x 17 and landscape

Tags: reporting-services

On my SSRS report I have set the Report Properties to Landscape, paper size to Tabloid and 17 width by 11 height with 0.25 margin. After I deployed the report and ran it on the web. Followed by exporting to Excel and printed it and it did not come out the format I have set on SSRS. Also, the I have bold the report lines by section based on the group and in Excel the bold report lines are not there.Please advise. I am thinking of moving to Crystal report might solve the problem. Any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite how page size works in SSRS. When you set the page size attribute, this will really only effect two things in SSRS.

1. How the report is displayed online. This is set via the `Interactive Page Size` setting, and really, only the height matters here.
2. `Page Size` sets the page size on the **PDF** export. We have this because PDFs are supposed to be a portable format, commonly used for printing.

Excel doesn't have this attribute as a part of the file. If you want to print to a specified page size/format, that's all handled at the time of printing by the print dialog.

Comment: Any ideas Crystal report will solve my problem? Or do you know any reporting software can invoke excel to pre diefined printing format? Thanks.

Comment: @Etex: I don't believe it would. The problem isn't your reporting environment, but Excel. Your best bet is to either get people to either export in PDF, or to properly print things in Excel. It's not particularly difficult.

Comment: In that case, any ideas if I can use excel as a template and connect to SQL server store procedure and retrieve the data and post it on the web. By doing so, I can default the excel template printing format without going thru SSRS. Let me know. Thanks.